# How to convert CSV to multi level nested JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

[How to convert CSV to nested JSON in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71583670/how-to-convert-csv-to-nested-json-in-python)
This is related to something like this.

I want to convert a flat dataframe file to Nested JSON format:

I have a csv (sales_2020) file in the following format:

[image]

**and i want a json like this:**

[image]

**i tried the link above and was able to add 1 level using this:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')

df['sales_2020'] = df[['computer','mobile']].to_dict('records')

out = df[['a','Sales_2020']].to_json(orient='records', indent=4)
```

But i was unable to add 1 more level to it..i.e sales for a specific month..I tried this below solution but doesnt work..

```
df['jan']['sales_2020'] =df[['computer','mobile']].to_dict('records')
```

please help me out

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want is `orient='index'`

```py
df['sales_2020'] = df[['computer','mobile']].to_dict('records')
out = df.set_index('Month')[['sales_2020']].to_json(orient='index', indent=4)
```

```
{
    "jan":{
        "sales_2020":{
            "computer":10,
            "mobile":5
        }
    },
    "feb":{
        "sales_2020":{
            "computer":8,
            "mobile":2
        }
    },
    "march":{
        "sales_2020":{
            "computer":6,
            "mobile":12
        }
    }
}
```